# How to write a use case that retrieves data from Android framework with Context

Tags: android, mvvm, use-case, android-mvvm, clean-architecture

I am migrating an application to MVVM and clean architecture, and I am missing one part of the puzzle.

**The problem domain:**

List all applications on device and display them in the Fragment / Activity

A device app is represented by its package name:

`data class DeviceApp(val packageName: String)`

This is how the device apps are listed:

```
private fun listAllApplications(context: Context): List<DeviceApp> {
    val ans = mutableListOf<DeviceApp>()

    val packageManager: PackageManager = context.applicationContext.packageManager
    val packages = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
    for (applicationInfo in packages) {
        val packageName = applicationInfo.packageName
        ans.add(DeviceApp(packageName))
    }

    return ans
}
```

As I understand, calling `listAllApplications()` should be done in a UseCase inside the 'Domain Layer', which is called by a `ViewModel`.

However `listAllApplications` receives a `Context`, and the Domain Layer should be plain code only.

In clean architecture / MVVM, in which layer should I put `listAllApplications(context)`?

And more generally, how should the ViewModel interact with Android framework APIs that require `Context` (location, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Domain Layer should be plain code only.**

**That's correct!**, but in my opinion it's partially correct. Now considering your scenario you need `context` at domain level. You shouldn't have `context` at domain level but in your need you should either choose other architecture pattern or consider it as exceptional case that you're doing this.

Considering you're using context at domain, you should always use `applicationContext` in spite of `activity context`, because earlier persists through out process.

> **How should the ViewModel interact with android framework APIs that require Context (location, etc.)?**

Whenever you need `Context` at ViewModel either you can provide it from UI as method parameter *(I.e. `viewModel.getLocation(context)`)* or else use `AndroidViewModel` as your parent class for `ViewModel` *(it provides `getApplication()` public method to access context through out ViewModel)*.

All I would like to point you out is that make sure you don't accidentally hold any View/Context globally inside ViewModel/Domain Layer, because it can make catastrophe like memory leaking or crashes at worse.

Comment: I feel that this shouldn't be an exceptional case, a lot of applications of not ALL need to access android framework with context, examples are endless.

I hoped/figured that there is an architectural guideline of how to do this correctly.
this is the architecture as i see it:


view->viewModel->(fetch data with/) useCase->repository->Entity

where usecase is plain code in domain that serves as single responsibility.
When I want to to do one thing the usecase will handle it for me, but i dont see a way to avoid context

therefor what would be a good architectural pattern to do this?

Comment: Basically your domain should not have context in first place, your repository should have that followed by view model. That's why I provided two pointers with different scenarios. First regarding domain stuff is partially acceptable other than second one.

Comment: Also note that domain should have code that is independent of platform *(So that can be reused across platforms like business logic abstraction)*, in here context is purely dependent of android framework and can not be at domain, so you should have this implementation at repository or view model (app) level.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem very cleanly with dependency-injection. If you aren't already using DI, you probably want to be, as it will greatly simplify your clean-architecture endeavours.

Here's how I'd do this with [Koin](https://insert-koin.io/) for DI.

First, convert your usecase from a function to a class. This allows for constructor injection:

```
class ListAllApplications(private val context: Context) {
  ...
}
```

You now have a reference to `context` inside your usecase. Great! We'll deal with actually providing the value of context in a moment.

Now you're thinking... but aren't usecases meant to use reusable functions? What's the guy on about with usecases being classes?

We can leverage the miracle that is `operator fun`s to help us here.

```
class ListAllApplications(private val context: Context) {
  operator fun invoke(): List<DeviceApp> {
    val ans = mutableListOf<DeviceApp>()

    val packageManager: PackageManager = context.applicationContext.packageManager
    val packages = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
    for (applicationInfo in packages) {
        val packageName = applicationInfo.packageName
        ans.add(DeviceApp(packageName))
    }

    return ans
  }
}
```

`invoke` is a special function which allows an instance of a class to be invoked as if it were a function. It effectively transforms our class into a function with an injectable constructor

And this allows us to continue to invoke our usecase in the ViewModel with the standard function invocation syntax:

```
class MyViewModel(private val listAllApplications: ListAllApplications): ViewModel {
  init {
    val res = listAllApplications()
  }
}
```

Notice that our `ListAllApplications` usecase is also being injected into the constructor of `MyViewModel`, meaning that the ViewModel remains entirely unaware of `Context`.

The final piece of the puzzle is wiring all this injection together with Koin:

```
object KoinModule {
  private val useCases = module {
    single { ListAllApplications(androidContext()) }
  }
  private val viewModels = module {
    viewModel { MyViewModel(get()) }
  }
}
```

Don't worry if you've never used Koin before, other DI libraries will let you do similar things. The key is that your `ListAllApplications` instance is being constructed by Koin, which provides an instance of `Context` with `androidContext()`. Your `MyViewModel` instance is also being constructed by Koin, which provides the instance of `ListAllApplications` with `get()`.

Finally you inject `MyViewModel` into the `Activity`/`Fragment` which uses it. With Koin that's as simple as:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment {
  private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModel()
}
```

Et Voilà!

Comment: Great !
But how can you test your viewModel in a unitTest where there isn't context ?

Comment: You'll need to mock the `ListAllApplications` usecase to provide an implementation that doesn't require Context. No change is necessary to `MyViewModel`, you just need to inject the `MockListAllApplications` instance to `MyViewModel` in your DI

Comment: Isn't there a memory leak storing Context in the use case class and saving it in the ViewModel?

Comment: The `Context` you inject into the UseCase should be the Context of the `Application`. This is what Koin does with `androidContext()`. When you use the Application Context you shouldn't introduce any memory leak, because the Application instance will already live for as long as the UseCase instance lives. Indeed, if you were using the Context of a specific Activity, you would create a leak, but using Application context in this way is safe